# Set Max value in yAxis jQuery Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts, max, yaxis

I want change the value of yAxis max in jQuery. Based on the istruction of $('#MyChart')series[0].setData, i need something that do this.

`var _Chart = $('#MyChart').highcharts();
_Chart.yaxis.setMax(40);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `yAxis` maximum value use `setExtremes` or `update` method:

```
_Chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(null, 40);
```

or:

```
_Chart.yAxis[0].update({
    max: 40
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rm1ejax7/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Answer (score 0):

Will try the following:

```
_Chart.yaxi.setExtremes(null, 40);
```

Null means min value is auto-detected.